# How can I extract secrets using GitHub Actions?

Tags: ssh, github-actions, secretsmanager

I have a fairly basic scenario. I made a dedicated ssh key for this purpose and added it to my repository secrets.

1. Code gets pushed to `master`
2. GitHub action uploads it to server using `ssh` by doing `echo "${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}" > key`.
3. After that I can use this key to connect to my server e.g. `ssh -i key devops@myserver.com lsb_release -a`

The problem is that for some reason GitHub actions cannot write it to file, it writes characters `***` instead of the actual secret value into the file. Therefore obviously I cannot connect to my server.

How can I connect with ssh using this secret? Is there a way to connect without using a file? Can someone who did this common scenario using GitHub actions shed some light?

Comment: I think this is more to do with github stopping the logging of secrets, rather than it not actually being there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The good solution is to use gpg for encrypting the key, adding it to a repo and decrypting it on the server using passphrase. The passprase should be stored as github project secret of course.

More info how I did it here: https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets

Comment: like mentioned on the linked page this is just intended as a workaround for large secrets and does not protect you from exposing secrets in logs. IMHO @bk2204 should be the accepted answer.

Comment: If you do it like this, your secret isn't protected from being printed into logs. This is not "the good solution", this is a somewhat dangerous workaround if your secret happens to be larger than 64kb.

Answer (score 100):

GitHub Actions should be able to write a secret to a file this way.  The reason you see the stars is that the log is filtered, so if a secret would be logged, it's replaced in the log with three asterisks instead.  This is a security measure against an accidental disclosure of secrets, since logs are often publicly available.

However, it's a good idea to avoid writing the secret to the log anyway if possible.  You can write your command like this so you don't write the secret to the log:

```
    - run: 'echo "$SSH_KEY" > key'
      shell: bash
      env:
        SSH_KEY: ${{secrets.SSH_KEY}}
```

All you'll see in the log is `echo "$SSH_KEY" > key`, not the secret or any asterisks.

Note that you do want quotes here, since the `>` character is special to YAML.

If this doesn't work to log into your server, there's likely a different issue; this technique does work for writing secrets in the general case.

Comment: I've struggled for a while and noticed that I'm missing the double quotes. `echo "$SSH_KEY"`. It was important to escape multiline characters.

Comment: I can't verify that. I updated the `run` to be `'echo "$SSH_KEY" > key && tail key'` and it
still shows `***`. How can the action runner know the file should be still encrypted?

Comment: @Dida The action runner knows all secrets. In case the secrets should be output, it replaces it by stars. What it cannot do is detecting variants of the secret. Thus, a ROT13 helps to output the secret for debugging or emergency recovery.

Answer (score 20):

I found a way to do this. We used GatsbyJS for a project and it relies on a
.env.production file for the env variables. I tried to pass them as
`env:` to the github action, but that didn't work and they were ignored.

Here is what I did. I base 64 encoded the .env.production file:

```
base64 -i .env.production
```

Added the output to an env variable in github action. Then in my action I do:

```
echo ${{ secrets.ENV_PRODUCTION_FILE }} | base64 -d > .env.production
```

This way the contents of my .env.production file ended being written to the machine that executes the github action.

Answer (score 7):

You can decode a `secret` by looping through it with python shell, like this:

```
    - name: Set env as secret
      env:
        MY_VAL: ${{ secrets.SUPER_SECRET }}
      run: |
        import os
        data = open("file", "w")
        for q in (os.getenv("MY_VAL")):
          print(q)
          data.write(q)
      shell: python
```

This will both print each character to stdout and store them in file called `file`. `stdout` will have an output like this, while file should have the secret string saved inside.

```
s
e
c
r
e
t
```

It runs daily on my repo, to check if it's still working:  [here](https://github.com/moro-drake/actions_sampler/actions/workflows/print_secret.yml)

Comment: For me it required changing `print q` to `print(q)`

Answer (score 4):

encode it and decode back

```
- run: 'echo "$SSH_KEY" | base64'
       shell: bash
       env:
         SSH_KEY: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
```

and decode it back `echo "<encoded string>" | base64 -d`

Answer (score 2):

```
echo ${{secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}} | sed 's/./& /g'
```

Answer (score 1):

I used sed in a GHA to replace a TOKEN in a file like this :

```
run: |-
     sed -i "s/TOKEN/${{secrets.MY_SECRET}}/g" "thefile"
```

The file looks like this:

```
    credentials "app.terraform.io" {
       token = "TOKEN"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to solve your actual problem of securely logging into an SSH server using a secret stored in GitHub Actions, named `GITHUB_ACTIONS_DEPLOY`.

Let's call this "beep", because it will cause an audible bell on the server you login to. Maybe you use this literally ping a server in your house when somebody pushes code to your repo.

```yaml
      - name: Beep    
        # if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/XXXX' # Maybe limit only this step to some branches
        run: |
          eval $(ssh-agent)
          ssh-add - <<< "$SSH_KEY"
          echo "* ssh-rsa XXX" >> /tmp/known_hosts # Get from your local ~/.ssh/known_hosts or from ssh-keyscan
          ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/tmp/known_hosts user@example.com "echo '\a'"
        env:
          SSH_KEY: ${{ secrets.PMT_GITHUB_ACTIONS_DEPLOY }}
```

If, actually you are using SSH as part of a rsync push task, here is how to do that:

```yaml
      - name: Publish    
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/XXX'
        run: |
          eval $(ssh-agent)
          ssh-add - <<< "$SSH_KEY"
          echo "* ssh-rsa XXX" >> /tmp/known_hosts
          rsync $FROM user@server:
        env:
          SSH_KEY: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_ACTIONS_DEPLOY }}
          RSYNC_RSH: "ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/tmp/known_hosts"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is whole actions config yaml that I just used.
It's a combination of answers above, just for convenience put in one config.

```
name: Production build
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - prod
jobs:
  extractor_job:
    runs-on: "self-hosted"
    steps:
      - run: 'echo "$DEPLOYER_SSH_KEY" | base64'
        shell: bash
        env:
          DEPLOYER_SSH_KEY: ${{secrets.DEPLOYER_SSH_KEY}}
      - run: 'echo "$DEPLOYER_SSH_PASSPHRASE" | base64'
        shell: bash
        env:
          DEPLOYER_SSH_PASSPHRASE: ${{secrets.DEPLOYER_SSH_PASSPHRASE}}
      - run: 'echo "$DEPLOYER_SSH_USERNAME" | base64'
        shell: bash
        env:
          DEPLOYER_SSH_USERNAME: ${{secrets.DEPLOYER_SSH_USERNAME}}
```

It encodes variables to base64 and which values can be extracted from "raw log"
[image: Access raw log]

For safe decode back to normal values I use Dev Toys from Microsoft.