# How can I use environment variables in flutter without adding a file in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart, github, environment-variables, github-actions

At the moment I am using [flutter_dotenv](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv) to load some environment variables from a file. It worked okay until I tried to create a GitHub Action that runs `flutter test`.

The file with the environment variables has to be added as an asset in `pubspec.yaml` acording to the documentation for the package so when I run the action I get the following error:

```
No file or variants found for asset: dotenv.
```

Where `dotenv` is the name of the file with environment variables. The reason I get the error is because `dotenv` is in `.gitignore` (obviously), so that file can't be found.

Is there a way to use environment variables in Flutter without having to add the file to pubspec.yaml? Or is it possible to add the file "locally" (meaning adding it to GitHub without having to track it with git) for the action in some way?

Comment: If I understand you right you would need add this file manually after a clean github fetch

Comment: Yes, that's what I do in my pipelines. I generally base64 encode the contents of the file in a secret, then in my action script, decode secret and write the content to a file. Here is a link to SO answer doing the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66603047/12132021

Comment: Why is `dotenv` "obviously" in `.gitignore`?  Do the environment variables contain secrets?  If so, then yes, referencing them in `pubspec.yaml` probably is inappropriate.  I don't have direct experience with GitHub Actions, but [you can set custom environment variables in the workflow configuration](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables).    You alternatively might want to look into using [`direnv`](https://direnv.net/), which allows an `.envrc` file to conditionally load a private environment file only if it exists.

Comment: jamesdlin, I just mean that it wouldn't have to be environment variables if it wasn't different for each environment. That's why the file is in `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thank you Jared, will look at that solution